# Flutter FirebaseFirestore multiple apps

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Im working on a flutter project, when i'm trying to connect to Firestore using a secondary firebase app.
see [Configure multiple projects](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects).

I get the following error when trying to connect to db

```
secAppFirestore
        .collection("yos")
```

:

> "Unhandled Exception: [core/no-app] No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has
> been created - call Firebase.initializeApp".

my code

```
void main() async {
  // Avoid errors caused by flutter upgrade.
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    name: "yostest2-xxxxx",
    options: FirebaseOptions(
      apiKey: "AIzaSy...",
      appId: "1:68080...",
      messagingSenderId: "",
      projectId: "yostest2-xxxxx",
      storageBucket: "yostest2-xxxxx.appspot.com",
      databaseURL: 'https://yostest2-xxxxx.firebaseio.com',
    ),
  );

  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

....

```
 void _incrementCounter() async {
    FirebaseApp secondaryApp = Firebase.app('yostest2-xxxxx');
    FirebaseFirestore secAppFirestore =
        FirebaseFirestore.instanceFor(app: secondaryApp);
    await secAppFirestore
        .collection("yos")
        .add({"timestamp": FieldValue.serverTimestamp()});

    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to call `Firebase.initializeApp();` which will initialize the default app before you call `Firebase.initializeApp(name: "yostest2-xxxxx",...)` for your secondary app. Place it above your current init line and await it as well.

If you encounter issues on hot reload then you may also have to track whether initializeApp has already been called via iterating Firebase.apps[].

Comment: Thanks that fix the error.  My goal was to init firebase without using google-services.json.  i dont want to call Firebase.initializeApp(); to default app.  Is it possible in flutter ?

Comment: Currently I don't believe so. See my response here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69542091/is-there-any-possibility-to-init-firebase-in-flutter-dynamically/69580350#69580350. Specifically review the github issue (and subsequent pull request) where others attempted to accomplish this using a workaround but were not successful. The PR looks to solve this but is in the early draft stages.

Answer (score 0):

If however you'd like to use Firestore with a secondary Firebase App, use the instanceFor method:

```dart
FirebaseApp secondaryApp = Firebase.app('SecondaryApp');
FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instanceFor(app: secondaryApp);
```

for more information you check this link :
https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/